# viewWillAppear flickering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, viewwillappear

I have a tabbar and on one tab I have a UIPickerView. To execute NSUserDefaults, I need to use viewWillAppear, but that causes a strange flickering each time I change from an other tab to this tab. The tab loads a local pdf file, and each time I switch back from an other tab to this tab it reloads the pdf. The flickering each time is really annoying, are there any ways to prevent the app to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the pdf before switching to the view and pass it as a parameter.